# Negative KL-divergence RLHF implementation

Tags: proximal-policy-optimization, kl-divergence, rlhf

I am struggling to understand one part of the [FAQ](https://huggingface.co/docs/trl/main/en/how_to_train) of the transformer reinforcement learning library from HuggingFace:

> **What Is the Concern with Negative KL Divergence?**
>
> If you generate text by purely sampling from the model distribution things work fine in general. But when you use the generate method there are a few caveats because it does not always purely sample depending on the settings which can cause KL-divergence to go negative. Essentially when the active model achieves log_p_token_active < log_p_token_ref we get negative KL-div. This can happen in a several cases:
>
> - top-k sampling: the model can smooth out the probability distribution causing the top-k tokens having a smaller probability than those of the reference model but they still are selected
> - min_length: this ignores the EOS token until min_length is reached. thus the model can assign a very high log prob to the EOS token and very low prob to all others until min_length is reached
> - batched generation: finished sequences in a batch are padded until all generations are finished. The model can learn to assign very low probabilities to the padding tokens unless they are properly masked or removed.
>
> These are just a few examples. Why is negative KL an issue? The total reward R is computed R = r - beta * KL so if the model can learn how to drive KL-divergence negative it effectively gets a positive reward. In many cases it can be much easier to exploit such a bug in the generation than actually learning the reward function. In addition the KL can become arbitrarily small thus the actual reward can be very small compared to it.

I understand why the KL-divergence that is computed here is an approximation that **can** be negative as opposed to the real one. However, I cannot wrap my head around the details of why these specific sampling parameters would lead to negative KL-divergence. Could someone elaborate on these points?

Comment: well KL is a distance, pretty sure that it cannot be negative by definition, so they're doing something sketchy